# How to require the file in sub directory in custom PHP MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, url-routing, bootstrapping

I have created a mvc structure in php just for the learning purposes in php. Which has been a simple success as I followed the online tutorial.

The directory structure for the current mvc :
app
 |-controllers
         1.php , 2.php , 3.php
 |-libs
         1.php , 2.php , 3.php
 |-views 
         1.php , 2.php , 3.php
 |-models 
         1.php , 2.php , 3.php
 |-public

the calling of controllers is done by a file called bootstrap.php in libs folder.

I have made some changes in the directory structure as :
app
 |-controllers
      |- module1
           1.php , 2.php , 3.php

```
  |- module2
       1.php , 2.php , 3.php
```

|-libs
 |-views
 |-models
 |-public

tried to integrate the changes in bootstrap.php for calling the controllers
from the called folders.

here is my

```
private $_modulePath = app/controllers/

private function _loadExistingModuleController() {
      $module = $this->_modulePath . $this->_url[0];
        if(is_dir($this->_modulePath . $this->_url[0]) == true) {
        $_dirpath =  $this->_modulePath . $this->_url[0] .'/';
            $file = $this->_dirpath . $this->_url[1];           
                  if (file_exists($file)) {
                require '$file';
                $this->_controller = new $this->_url[1];
                $this->_controller->loadModel($this->_url[1], $this->_modelPath);
            } else {
                $this->_error();
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $this->_error();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

i am receiving Undefined offset:

any suggestion on how to do the above.
Thanks.

Comment: Undefine offset on which line or in which code?

Comment: made some changes now at line $file = $this->_dirpath . $this->_url[1]; it says undefined property.

Comment: Can you please update the question with the problem you currently have? I think that message "undefined property" is clear enough. $this->_dirpath is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

`$this->_dirpath` has not been defined, you are defining  `$_dirpath` instead.

**Solution:**

To fix your latest problem change:

```
$_dirpath =  $this->_modulePath . $this->_url[0] .'/';
```

to

```
$this->_dirpath =  $this->_modulePath . $this->_url[0] .'/';
```

Comment: any other better way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean? You are trying to use a property that's not defined! Defining it before using is the only way.